# Facebook Page Owner Verification

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-page

We are building the application which allows venue owners to send specific messages to their customers through the Android apps.
One challenge is the process of venue owner verification (the DB of venues is crowdsourced), and we are on the track to find the best and easiest way of doing the verification.

So, the task is:

1. we know the venue name and its address
2. we know the venue ID on Facebook (Venue facebook page reference)

The question is: *Is there any FB API which allows us to verify whether user is the owner of specific FB page or not?*

For example, the process will be following:

- venue owner goes to our site
- venue owner searches for his venue
- venue owner connects to FB
- we are verifying whether he manages the page connected to this venue

Comment: Sorry, accidentally voted to close - had wrong tab open

Answer (score 2):

When you get the `manage_pages` permission from a user you can access a list of the pages they admin at `/<user id>/accounts` - this is the only way to check if a user is the admin of a specific page unless your app is being accessed as a tab on that page.

In that case, the `signed_request` sent with the tab loads contains a `page` element telling you if the current users likes / is an admin of the page, as well as the page ID